# ArrayAdapter / ListView position 0 not being detected

Tags: android, listview, fragment, adapter

I would like to put a medal image for position 1, 2, 3 and hide it for the following items in an `arrayadapter` combined with a `listview`.

Curiously, after testing, it seems that position is returned properly (the Pin indicator), and my idea works for position 1 and 2 (so items 2 and 3), but not for position 0. The attached image will explain better i think.

The code is under the image.

[image]

```
public class TopHorecaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TopHorecaElement> {

private final List<TopHorecaElement> mTopHorecas;
private final Context mContext;

TextView horeca_name;
TextView horeca_type;
TextView horeca_address;
TextView horeca_pins;

ImageView horeca_medal;

CircularImageView image;

public TopHorecaAdapter(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final List<TopHorecaElement> objects){
    super(context, R.layout.fragment_top_horecas, objects);
    mTopHorecas = objects;
    mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent){

    final TopHorecaElement topHorecaElement = mTopHorecas.get(position);
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_top_horeca, parent, false);
    }

    Integer pst = position;

    horeca_name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tophoreca_name);
    horeca_type = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tophoreca_asl);
    horeca_address = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tophoreca_pinnumber);
    horeca_pins = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tophoreca_address);
    horeca_medal = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tophoreca_medal);

    horeca_name.setText(topHorecaElement.getBarName());
    horeca_pins.setText(topHorecaElement.getNbr() + " Pin'Ups");
    horeca_address.setText(pst.toString());
    horeca_type.setText("");

    horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.first);

    if (pst <= 0) {
        horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.first);
    } else if (pst == 1) {
        horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.second);
    } else if (pst == 2) {
        horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.third);
    } else if (pst > 2 && pst < mTopHorecas.size()){
        horeca_medal.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.first);
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

**Here is the code from the fragment:**

```
@Override
void initEvent(@Nullable final View view) { HorecaPinDataManager.getTopHoreca(PinUpApplication.getInstance().user.getCity());}

@Subscribe
public void onTopHorecaEventReceived(TopHorecasReceivedEvent event){
    try {
        if (!event.mTopHoreca.isEmpty()) {
            adapter = new TopHorecaAdapter(getActivity(), event.mTopHoreca);
            mTopHoreca.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            HorecaPinDataManager.getAlltimeTopHoreca(PinUpApplication.getInstance().user.getCity());
        }
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException e){
        HorecaPinDataManager.getAlltimeTopHoreca(PinUpApplication.getInstance().user.getCity());
    }
}

@Subscribe
public void onTopAlltimeHorecaEventReceived(TopAlltimeHorecasReceivedEvent event){
    adapter = new TopHorecaAdapter(getActivity(), event.mTopHoreca);
    mTopHoreca.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It seems that if only the first event is triggered, the icon shows. It doesn't work only if the second event is triggered `(onAlltimeTopHorecaEvent)`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the error comes from the fragment code, since it works for the first Event reception (so, if TopHorecasReceivedEvent is not empty, do the code...) works. If it's empty, I call my API again and receive other elements, and this is where the mentioned problem is..

Answer (score 0):

Would you try that?

```
try{
horeca_medal = (ImageView)getApplicationContext().findViewById(R.id.horeca_medal);
//Write your own reference.

horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.first);

    if (pst <= 0) {
        horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.first);
    } else if (pst == 1) {
        horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.second);
    } else if (pst == 2) {
        horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.third);
    } else if (pst > 2 && pst < mTopHorecas.size()){
        horeca_medal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //This edit
    } else {
        horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.first);
    }
}catch(Excaption ex)
{
android.util.Log.e("YourError", ex.getMessage());
}
```

Can you give us the LogMessage result?

Comment: Hi, it seems there is no error message whatsoever unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
Integer pst = position
```

to

```
int pst = position
```

should solve your problem.

EDIT:

Okay, so you always set your image to `drawable.first` before you start.

```
horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.first);
if (pst == 1) {
    horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.second);
} else if (pst == 2) {
    horeca_medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.third);
} else if(pst > 2) {
    horeca_medal.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
}
```

should work and if it doesn't I have no idea what is heppening.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have already tried this before, and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @VanhaerenThomas Edited. If it does not work, I give up :D

Comment: I really don't get it where this is coming from. Anyway, I have tried your code as well and it doesn't work. This doesn't make any sense. Thanks a lot anyway!